# Hyperas: 'List' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to read in some data from a TSV file for use with [Hyperas](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas), but any way I do it, I seem to get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/cnn_search.py", line 233, in <module>
    trials=trials)
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas/optim.py", line 67, in minimize
    verbose=verbose)
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperas/optim.py", line 133, in base_minimizer
    return_argmin=True),
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 312, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin,
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 635, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin)
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 325, in fmin
    rval.exhaust()
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 204, in exhaust
    self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.async)
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 178, in run
    self.serial_evaluate()
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 97, in serial_evaluate
    result = self.domain.evaluate(spec, ctrl)
  File "~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 840, in evaluate
    rval = self.fn(pyll_rval)
  File "~/temp_model.py", line 218, in keras_fmin_fnct
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

From other questions that I've seen, this error is caused by using regular arrays where NumPy arrays should be used. So, I've tried to convert the TSV I'm reading to NumPy arrays at every step:

```
from hyperas import optim
...
import numpy as np
import csv

def data():
    dataPath="/path/to/fm.labeled.10m.txt"

    X = []
    Y = []
    with open(dataPath) as dP:
            reader = csv.reader(dP, delimiter="\t")
            for row in reader:

                    #skip the first two columns, and the last column is labels
                    X.append(np.array(row[2:-1]))

                    #labels
                    Y.append(row[-1])


    encoder = LabelBinarizer()
    Y_categorical = encoder.fit_transform(Y)

    #split data into test and train 
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y_categorical, test_size=0.25)

    X_train_np = np.array(X_train)
    X_test_np = np.array(X_test)

    Y_train_np = np.array([np.array(y) for y in Y_train])
    Y_test_np = np.array([np.array(y) for y in Y_test])

    return X_train_np, Y_train_np, X_test_np, Y_test_np

...
trials = Trials()
best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model_name,
                                      data=data,
                                      algo=tpe.suggest,
                                      max_evals=numRuns,
                                      trials=trials)
```

I also imagine that there's a more efficient way to do this, without creating so many intermediate arrays—and that'd be great, because I'll be reading in millions of rows of data.

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit*: [Hyperopt wiki](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin) describes `Trials`.

Comment: Please, read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and follow its suggestions by updating your post.

Comment: For example, what is `Trials`? We can't see its definition. Anyway, we need a verifiable example.

Comment: What is `keras_fmin_fnct`?

Comment: @nbro Will do. the definition of `trials` is shown: `trials = Trials()`, which is a Hyperas/Hyperopt object. I can add a link to the wiki.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not completely sure. It looks like an internal Keras/Hyperas function: https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/blob/master/hyperas/optim.py . I don't, unfortunately, have access to `temp_model.py` directly: it's created as a temp file and written to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered using `np.genfromtxt('your_file.tsv')`?
works wonders for reading in csv and tsv data, and i have had great experiences with it lately. Also, you should problably supply more information on your specific problem (kind of data, layout etc) if you need a more detailed answer.

Comment: This is great! I'm using `np.loadtxt()` though since I have no missing data.